# Is it possible to set instance variables on class methods that are only visible to the current method and any method it calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have the following:

```rb
class MyClass
    class << self
        def call(req_id)
            @request_id = req_id
            method_1
            method_2
        end
        
        def method_1
            puts "method 1 - req id: #{@request_id}"
            sleep(@request_id)
        end
        
        def method_2
            puts "method 2 - req id: #{@request_id}"
        end
    end
end

def func3
    MyClass.call(6)
end

def func4
    MyClass.call(2)
end

t1 = Thread.new{func3()}
sleep(1)
t2 = Thread.new{func4()}
t1.join
t2.join
```

And this produces the following output:

```
method 1 - req id: 6
method 1 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 2
```

This makes sense since the class instance variable `request_id` gets changed by `func4`. But is there a way that we can make `request_id` specific only to it's own thread such that we get the following result:

```
method 1 - req id: 6
method 1 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 6
```

I can accomplish this by straight up passing `req_id` to `func3` and `func4` but would like to avoid that if possible.

Is this possible to do by using instance vars?

Comment: It seems like you're hoping for instance behavior out of class methods. Why not use instance methods instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use instance methods

Just create instances in class method

Like this as idea

```rb
class MyClass
  class << self
    def call(req_id)
      new(req_id).call
    end
  end

  def call
    method1
    method2
  end

  private

  def initialize(req_id)
    @request_id = req_id
  end

  def method1
    puts "method 1 - req id: #{@request_id}"
    sleep(@request_id)
  end

  def method2
    puts "method 2 - req id: #{@request_id}"
  end
end

def func3
  MyClass.call(6)
end

def func4
  MyClass.call(2)
end

t1 = Thread.new { func3 }

sleep(1)

t2 = Thread.new { func4 }

t1.join
t2.join
```

```
# will print
method 1 - req id: 6
method 1 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 2
method 2 - req id: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with dirty tricks: You could create the variable, and it will then be visible to the methods you are calling, but before you return from your "root" method, you have to destroy the variable again (using `remove_instance_variable`), lest it would continue to exist for the lifetime of this object.

For the same reason, you have to be careful with exceptions. Therefore I would place the `remove_instance_variable` into an `ensure` clause, to make sure that it is executed even if the method is left prematurely by an exception.

However it may be better tor rethink your design. Instead of creating and destroying instance variables on the fly, consider creating them in the constructor and set them to `nil` initially. Instead of removing the variable, set it to `nil` again.

Comment: Wouldn't thread locals be better than creating/destroying instance variables (which would still have contention issues)?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Do they make sense, if we have only a single thread? AFIK, their purpose is to ensure that each thread can have its own set of local variables.

Comment: Right, and this example has multiple threads.